# Get 100 entries with foreach every time

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach, limit

I have 10,000 users in the database and I'm planning to send them emails in bundles of 100. Basically I need to use foreach to get 100 users and send the email, and then get the next 100 and send and so on.

What I've managed to do is to use foreach to limit the number to 100. But lost as to how to get the next 100. Code:

```
$email_preliminary = $this->db->select('email')->get('user');
$email_raw = array();

$counter = 0;
foreach ($email_preliminary->result() as $row):
    $email_raw[] = $row->email;

    $counter++;

    if ($counter == 99) {
        break;
    }

endforeach;
```

Advice appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: use for loop instead. for($i=0;$i>count($email_preliminary->result());$i++){} and set $loop = 100; and increment 100 after each 100 entry

Comment: or do it on SQL level

Comment: PHP is not made for long task, but you can reload the page after performing and passthrough where the script was. Then in the MySQL query you can use LIMIT to say what part the script needs to grab from the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$mails = Array() ;
foreach ($email_preliminary->result() as $row)
{
        $mails[] = $row->email ;
}

$tab = array_chunk($mails,100) ;

foreach ( $tab as $mail_lot )
{
    $mails_to_send = implode(',',$mail_lot) ; // Contains mail1@test.com,mail2@test.com,mail3@test.com... for 100 entries
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Awesome!

Comment: One more thing Pierre. Does this function take into account the remaining emails if my total number of emails can't be divided by 100? Thanks,

Comment: Yes it will, the last packet will be 100 or less users and the foreach parse it all so you will got all of them

Answer (score 0):

One thing to consider, is what happens when your email list doesn't divide by 100? You will need to account for this after the loop!

```
$email_preliminary = $this->db->select('email')->get('user');

$email_raw = array(); // Set an empty array

foreach ($email_preliminary->result() as $row)
{
    $email_raw[] = $row->email; // Add emails to the array

    // The calculation below will return zero if the number of email
    // addresses in $email_raw is divisible by 100

    if ( (count($email_raw) % 100) == 0 )
    {
        // yourSendEmailFunction($email_raw);
        $email_raw = array(); // Reset the array
    }
}

// If you have 10,001 emails, $email_raw will still contain 1 email address
// Make sure you mail these people

if ( ! empty($email_raw))
{
    // yourSendEmailFunction($email_raw);
}
```